# Change a Sql-Server (express) from a named instance to localhost?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to change a mssql express from a named instance to localhost?

When first installing the server I gave my mssql express server, a name. Now, working on a project where the web.config specifcs the localhost, or (local), I have to edit all of these before I migrate the db or run the application.

To connect to my database, I have to specify my instance instead of localhost like so: `MyComputerName\Instance;Database=db_name;"`

I would like to simply use: `localhost;Database=db_name;` This currently does not work.

I don't want to have to re-install mssql, however I have considered this an option if no other options are avaiable.

I am using "Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services" version 10.50.2550.0

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you don't specify an instance name when connecting to a server, it will look at port `1433`.

By default, the **MSSQLSERVER** instance (i.e. the default) will be assigned this static port.

By default, any named instances will be assigned dynamic ports which are discovered using the SQL Server Browser service.

You might not be able to rename an instance, but you can change its port number.

For your named instance, you need to set it to the static default SQL Server port, i.e. `1433`. Obviously TCP/IP will need to be enabled for the instance:

[image]

Once you've done this, should be able to connect to `localhost` without supplying a name as it will just try and connect to `1433`.

Comment: I only specified port 1433 on IPAll, and that works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian Preston : Isnt the 1433 default port which creates a security leak? Can you please shed some light

Answer (score 16):

[This is what worked for me.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2928/updating-the-tcp-port-on-a-sql-server-cluster-node/)

1) Go to SQl Server Configuration Manager

2) Open SQL Server Network Configuration

3) Click on my Named Instance

4) Open TCP/IP

5) Click on IP addresses

6) Added port 1433 to all ip's

**(Edit)**

It may be necessary to run the SQL Server Configuration Manager as an **admin** if the port is uneditable.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the *Server* name, but not the Instance name.  The only way to change it is to re-install.