# doubts about ssms server name : Why we are using dot and can we change that once we are connected and how

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql server. I just want to know

1. why we are using `.` in server name in ssms.
2. Can we change the server name .
3. How can we do that?
4. I googled some where and found that we need to add \ and blabla..can somebody pls answer me 
   what is the convintion we are using for server name.

Answer (score 2):

A dot in the server name just a short form for writing the local machine name. You find more about that in this SO question [SQL Server Connection Strings - dot(“.”) or “(local)” or “(localdb)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217518/sql-server-connection-strings-dot-or-local-or-localdb).

You can also use a ip address and more in the server name field.