# Configure connection string to SQL Server Express to work with every computer/server name

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-express, sql-server-2012-express

How do I have to configure my SQL Server Express connection string that the server attribute accepts the computername where the SQL Server is running aka the current machine:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbConn1" 
         connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>       
</connectionStrings>
```

I have seen somewhere a configuration like the above where the server attribute has the `.\SQLEXPRESS` value.

What does that dot notation mean?

Comment: The dot basically means "localhost".

Comment: IMO, you can refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217518/sql-server-connection-strings-dot-or-local-or-localdb) for more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDbConn1" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>       
</connectionStrings>
```

If it is a named instance with a different name than "SQLEXPRESS" or the SQL instance is exposed on a port other than 1433, you will have to change that in the connection string as well.  Typically, if there is only one SQL instance, `Server=localhost` will totally suffice.

Does it not work, simply by referencing localhost or 127.0.0.1.

If not, you may have to go to SQL Server Configuration Manager, navigate to TCP/IP, click the IP addresses tab and enable 127.0.0.1.

Also, I think it is `Trusted Connection=True` not `Trusted Connection=Yes`, but maybe that works...?