# Failed to read database schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, petapoco

im newbie in c# and i want fetch data from mssql local engine with peta poco orm but i get this error
[image of error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn2Gt.png)
and here is my connection string of my class library:

```
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="School" connectionString="Data Source= MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=School;user id=sa; Password=1qaz!QAZ;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

my database name is School, i tried server too, and my server name which i use to connect to ssms is DESKTOP-KVEJKDS
thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to connect to an SQL server on localhost, so you should set `Data Source=.;`

Comment: A little info about what the dot `.` means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218301/3034273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your Data Source name with your Server name:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="School" connectionString="Data Source= DESKTOP-KVEJKDS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=School;user id=sa; Password=1qaz!QAZ;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```